# converting several mkv files to avi at once

Tags: convert, mkv, mencoder, arista-transcoder

My crappy samsung will not read anything that has a .mkv extension. There's no way to install another video player since the android version is no longer 'updatable'.

Since 99% of video files right now are .mkv, there's something I can do to convert several files at once to .avi? I tried mencoder and it didn't work even with one single file. Arista just doesn't want to work either...

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: lubuntu 16.04...

Comment: Please don’t put “SOLVED” into the question title. [Accept an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine:

```
for i in *mkv; do ffmpeg -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i.mp4; done
```

Comment: Thanks. The video created in this way are not played well (no image). The phone opens them as mp3...

Answer (score 0):

You can try  ffmpeg with a script:

```
 for i in *.avi;

    do name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;

    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${name}.mkv";

 done
```

This will take all avi files the working directory and convert them into mkv with the same name.

Comment: That's cool. I want actually do the opposite, converting several mkv to avi. It will work if I just replace mkv with avi and vice versa in your script?